# Getting 404 on my heroku react app after deploy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, webpack

Tried any possible configuration, still after deployment to Heroku i get 404 (not found)
Any advise?

**package.json**
[package.json](https://github.com/erezoren/alef-bet-lotem/blob/master/package.json)

**webpack.config.js**
[webpack](https://github.com/erezoren/alef-bet-lotem/blob/master/webpack.config.js)

**Heroku config**
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP:    false
NODE_MODULES_CACHE:    false
NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION: false
SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK:  true
YARN_PRODUCTION:       false

**Project tree**

[Project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VT0k.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved.....i forgot to set the node buildpack in Heroku